# How to retrieve the number of pages of a document in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, pdf, ghostscript

I'm running an application that can use NodeJs to add functionalities that are not readily available.
I need to find out the number of pages of pdf files, as well as transform them into tiff files.

I want to use ghostscript4js with npm to realise that.

I have no issue in converting the pdf into tiff file, but I hit a roadblock to find the number of pages.

To find the number of pages of a pdf document, I used the following that works when run as a windows command:
`gswin64c -q -dNODISPLAY -dNOSAFER --permit-file-read="pdfdevice.pdf" -c "(""pdfdevice.pdf"") (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"`
where pdfdevice.pdf is my pdf file as an example.

This returns succesfully 43.

When using NodeJs, I wrote the following:

```
const omnis_calls = require('omnis_calls');
let autoSendResponse = true; // Set to false in methods which should not send a response to Omnis when they exit. (e.g. async methods)

/**
declare ghostscript package
*/
'use strict'
    

/**
 * Implement all of your publicly accessible methods in methodMap.
 */

const methodMap = {
    Pagecount:async function(param,response) {
        autoSendResponse = false;
         /*******
        param.C1 is the pdf source file path
        This function returns the number of pages.
        ********/
        var cmd = ['-q','-dNODISPLAY', '-dNOSAFER', '--permit-file-read='+param.C1,'-c "("'+param.C1+'") (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"']
       //let cmd = ['-q', '-dNODISPLAY', '-dNOSAFER', '--permit-file-read="pdfdevice.pdf"','-c "(""pdfdevice.pdf"") (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"'] 
       
      
       gs.execute(cmd)
        .then(function (value) {
             obj = {
                err: 0,
                message: value
            }
            omnis_calls.sendResponse(obj,response)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            obj = {
                err: 1,
                message: err.toString()
            }
            omnis_calls.sendResponse(obj,response)
        });
       
    },

    GSVersion: function (param, response) {
        autoSendResponse = false;
        let version = gs.version();
        obj = {
            err: 0,
            message: version
        }
        omnis_calls.sendResponse(obj,response);
    },

    GSVersion: function (param, response) {
        autoSendResponse = false;
        let version = gs.version();
        obj = {
            err: 0,
            message: version
        }
        omnis_calls.sendResponse(obj,response);
    }

};


module.exports = {
    call: function (method, param, response) { 

        autoSendResponse = true;

        if (methodMap[method]) {
            const result = methodMap[method](param, response);
            if (autoSendResponse)
                omnis_calls.sendResponse(result, response);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            throw Error("Method '" + method + "' does not exist");
        }

    }
};
```

I was expecting to get the number of pages in teh variable "value", but it is not defined.
I tried multiple approaches like `const pages=gs.execute(cmd)` without any success.

using methods to get the gs version, to convert a pdf to tiff works fine, so the issue must be in the Pagecount function.

Any idea how to get the value to be returned properly?

Comment: Ignore GS for a moment: what happens when you ```join.(` `)``` that `cmd` variable? Does it match what you're running on the command line? (hint: it doesn't). So one thing you'll want to do is stop using legacy string composition with `+` and instead use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) so you can be more confident that what you're writing in your strings is the same as what you're writing on the CLI.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for your comments.  I'm very new on Javascript so thanks for helping me.  I learned and tried template strigns but I didn't get much further.